# how could I add item(as a first item) to arrayList

Tags: java, android

in my application I want add some value to arrayList and I want that added item will be first item of arrayList. I use this code

```
Sphere[] spheres = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getJSONArray("data").toString(),Sphere[].class);
                mSphereList = Arrays.asList(spheres);
                Sphere sphere = new Sphere();
                sphere.setId(0);
                sphere.setTitle("All");
                mSphereList.add(0,sphere);
                mListView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,mSphereList));
```

When I run my application I got exception

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
```

What I did wrong here. Could you tell me a good solution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` doesn't return an ArrayList. It returns a list with a fixed size, backed by the original array (as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)).

You have to create a real ArrayList:

```
mSphereList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(spheres));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add at specified index

```
list.add(1, object1)
list.add(2, object3)
list.add(2, object2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I know this but I want add item after Array.asList method.

Answer (score 0):

[`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) will give you back a **fixed size** list, and that is why your add is failing. You need to use:

```
mSphereList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(spheres));
```